# JS Function calling displaying odd text & not working more than once

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem, when I run my function "addMoney(amount)" (shown below) it works and shows the following: 100[object HTMLButtonElement]

My question is this, is there a way to get rid of the [object HTMLButtonElement] while keeping the number from moneyAmount when the function is called? And additionally, is there a way to call the function multiple times and add the money accordingly? As it only works the first time I call it, calling it more than once with the same or different amounts of moneyAmount displays no more or no less than what displays the first time.

My HTML:

```
<li class="item_shown" id="money">Shrill:  <button class="moneyButton" id="moneyAmount">0</button></li>
```

Calling the function in HTML:

```
<a class="button" onclick="javascript:addMoney('100');">Add 100 Money</a>
```

My JS Function:

```
function addMoney(amount) {
document.getElementById('moneyAmount')
var newBalance = amount + moneyAmount;
document.getElementById('moneyAmount').innerHTML = newBalance;
}
```

Comment: Get rid of global state, and clearly your moneyamount contains reference to a dom object, whereas you want it to be amount of sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text inside an element is considered to be a text node and since the button node has no other children, is the button node's first child.  The text node's value (in this case "0") is the value of its nodeValue property.  Assigning a new value to the nodeValue will change the text displayed.  So in your case the following code should work:

```
function addMoney(amount) {
  var node = document.getElementById('moneyAmount');
  var textNode = node.childNodes[0];
  var moneyAmount = parseInt(textNode.nodeValue, 10);
  textNode.nodeValue = amount + moneyAmount;}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked. I don't know much about nodes and children, so I'll be looking into that a bit more, for the moment though the above works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In your JavaScript, `+ moneyAmount;` does not do anything. It returns what you see: `[object HTMLButtonElement]`.

I think you want to add some numbers but it's not yet completely clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Could you elaborate?

Chris

EDIT:
Thank you for clarifying your question.

Try updating your function like this:

```
function addMoney(amount) {
    var oldBalance = document.getElementById('moneyAmount').value;
    var newBalance = amount + oldBalance;
    document.getElementById('moneyAmount').innerHTML = newBalance;
}
```

Comment: .What I'm trying to do is get the number 0 from id moneyAmount to change as players gain or lose "money". So in the above code that I had, the player starts with 0 money. I called a function that say "addMoney(100)" and want it to add to the moneyAmount, so the final value in moneyAmount would be 100, or whatever I had in the addMoney(). However, I don't want to just replace it with X money, I want to add what is there and with what is being given with addMoney. Now that you point it out though, I see why it isn't working, but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Just changed the function... the "[object HTMLButtonElement]" no longer appears, however if I call the function a second time, it only replaces the old amount with the new amount, not adding them which is what I would like it to do. Thanks for the help so far, do you know how to fix this though? EDIT: another answer solved it. Thanks for trying though

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't able to come up with the desired answer. Thank you for upvoting my attempt though. I'm glad it's fixed now! Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Try to find value by **document.getElementById('moneyAmount').innerHTML** and use some global variable say total_value to store retrieved value and then for each function call try to add the retrieved value to the previously stored value.